# Is there any feature to notify moderators in chat?

Tags: support

The question is simple:

Is there any feature to notify moderators in chat without using their name?

For example `@mod` instead of `@Seth`.

Here my intention is to send message to moderators in **chat** (So nothing personnel ). As per my knowledge, moderators keep an eye on chat room as well.

I am just asking to know Is there any such feature?

Comment: Message about what?

Comment: nothing personnel, for example regarding flagging a question or getting clarity in any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a heavily downvoted feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126988/270345) - unlikely to ever be implemented. For the general case, post a question on meta. Moderators are notified of questions on meta. Of course, search first, and search diligently.

Comment: " Moderators are __notified__ of questions on meta"--good point, I have learned now.

Comment: The simple answer is "no such feature" =)